# High Cpu Usage in Android

Tags: android, adb

Cpu measure with terminal

I have developed a graph drawing application using Kotlin. I utilized the Androidplot library and initially measured the CPU usage using the Android Studio Profiler, which indicated a range of 25% to 32% CPU usage. However, I decided to perform an additional measurement using the adb shell (top command). Upon executing the top command, I encountered the following statistics:[Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uCsP.png)
I found it perplexing that the CPU usage was reported as 124%.

Comment: Looks like you don't work with Linux, because then you would know that on Linux the CPU utilization is counted per core (1 core fully working =100%). So 124% means 1.25 cores are active. Android Studio defines 100% as all cores are active. So on a quad core system 25% CPU means 1 core is fully working.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/707203/top-command-on-ubuntu-multicore-cpu-shows-cpu-usage-100